# On what amount of work does using OpenMP start making sense?

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I recently started looking on parallelization using OpenMP and found a decent amount of good resources describing how to use it. However, I was unable to find documentation on when parallelization starts making sense or in other words: where is the turning point where parallelization start compensating the overhead of OpenMP's thread creation and in what cases is it better to go without it? How complex has work to be so it makes sense to parallelize it?

Is there any documentation or guide available on that?

Comment: You usually have to just experiment. You have some work and you don't know if parallelizing it will help. So you try it and see it. There's usually too many factors at play unless it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, if your computation is well suited for parallelization, you can expect substantial gain if the serial computation (for example the loop you want to parallelize) takes a few milliseconds.
Below 1 millisecond, it will not help to use multiple threads due to the overhead involved.

Comment: Yeah, probably that is the way to go. I just hoped to see some statistics on performance of specific constructs on different hardware, compilers and operating systems without testing everything by myself. Through lack of such, I'll go your way.

Answer (score 0):

Image processing would be one good example...
I used it when running sift and surf on two consecutive images..
I find it useful if you need to do heavy mathematical calculations especially on matrixes..